# What is the period after a game's main story line ends called?

Tags: terminology

Sometimes after you finish a game main storyline the game doesn't end there, and presents other opportunities to finish old quests or perhaps unlock new areas.

Examples of this are like Fallout 3 (with DLC), which allowed you to continue playing and completing quests even after the game's main storyline had completed. In fact, it opened up new quests that were previously unavailable had the main storyline not be completed. Another example is Final Fantasy 4 for the GBA; after completion of the game and the defeat of the final boss, you were allowed to access secret areas that opened on the maps as well as take on challenge bosses for fun.

I am looking for the terminology to describe this.

Comment: When I finished my New Vegas it did actually end. I didn't expect it to, but it did. All of items I picked up in the last quest, wasted.

Comment: As one very specific example of the term, Kingdom of Loathing calls it "aftercore", as a play on the "hardcore" and "softcore" modes (which both end when aftercore starts).

Comment: @Bobson I play KoL too but I thought that term was only local to KoL itself, and not as a general term for post-game

Comment: Over decades of gaming post game has stuck out as the most common for me. End game seems to have become more popular since the advent of mmorpgs but I would still use post game. Epilogue has never been common as far as I have seen but mash ups of post story/main quest etc have.

Comment: IIRC Chuggaaconroy (a YouTube Let's Player) usually refers to it as the aftergame.

Comment: I've voted to close based on http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11467/do-we-want-to-support-is-there-a-term-for-x-questions. Terminology questions need to be bounded to a specific game.

Comment: Except others disagree with your assertion, and there is no accepted community agreement.

Comment: @Frank I find it ironic you are forcing your own opinions on others. Your cited linked question doesn't have an accepted answer, and your answer is the most downvoted answer in the entire thread.

Comment: @misuzu Accepted answer means nothing.  Look at the most upvoted answer.  These are *bad* questions.  Popular, yes.  And that's why they're still open.  Doesn't mean they're good.  There's no forcing.  Just trying to keep site quality up, which these questions actively bring down.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

"Post-completion" or "post-game" is what I commonly hear. Sometimes people will qualify it as "post-main-quest" or similar.

This is distinct from "new game plus" types of replayability that simply restarts the game allowing you to keep some stats or items or whatnot.

Answer (score 39):

I would call it the **epilogue**.

Comment: As I recall, Lunar 2: Eternal Blue specifically refers to theirs as the Epilogue.

Comment: I think that epilogue usually means the last part of the main story (often explaining what happens long term in the game world), not the part after the main story.

Comment: @svick epilogue can fit but it is a bit vague. Quote from wikipedia: "Some epilogues may feature scenes only tangentially related to the subject of the story. They can be used to hint at a sequel or wrap up all the loose ends." In my opinion finishing the side quests is like wrapping all the loose ends. Although the wiki-article is based on literature and film.

Comment: Games are a form of story telling, and the epilogue is post climax. Though, I have always hated it.

Answer (score 11):

There is not widely agreed upon terminology for the example you've given (ability to play content which you could have played before completing the game after completing it).  As others have already answered terms like "Epilogue" or "Post-game" are fairly common.

There are some more specific cases of "play after completion" with more well-defined terminology though.

**End-game** refers to content which can only be accessed after "completion".  This is most commonly used in terms of MMOs where it refers to things that you can only do after reaching max level (like Raids in *World of Warcraft*).  Another example would be *Pokémon* which often has features that can only be used after defeating the Elite Four and/or the Champion.

**New Game Plus** refers starting a new game and importing some benefit from the completed save.  Usually this is something like keeping your level in an RPG, so it's like you are continuing your progression.

Comment: -1 The MMO "end-game" is something so VASTLY different from what has been asked here. Incredibly misleading. Shouldn't be here.

Comment: @Lohoris *Pokémon* end-game is precisely what he was asking about.  Given that I explained exactly how this term is used in MMOs I don't see how it could be misleading.

Comment: The "Elder Game" is what it seems to get called in MMO dev circles - I suspect the term was coined by Richard Bartle.

Answer (score 11):

The LEGO series of games normally allows "free play" after the main quests are done. You may go back and complete optional objectives that you did not complete before. In addition, there may be bonuses that are impossible to get on the first playthrough. For example, perhaps level 1 has a secret requiring a specific ability to achieve, but the LEGO character with that ability only becomes available in level 4.

Comment: "Free play" is the term I've most commonly heard for "continued play without game termination at the end of the main quest."

Answer (score 10):

I've always considered this to be called the "post game".

As another example the Pokemon series has lots of content after you see the game's credits.

Answer (score 2):

In literature its called [denouement](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/denouement), the part, after the main action, where loose ends are tied up.

Comment: And what makes your answer any different from what Benubird's answer was?

Comment: @memescientist Better spelling?

Answer (score 2):

I've heard it called, and call it myself, the Post-Game sandbox, which to me includes side missions that you start after the main "game" is finished.

Answer (score 1):

First word that comes to mind is, `denoument`.

Definition: *The events following the climax of a drama or novel in which such a resolution or clarification takes place.*

Although this might better asked on https://english.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Denoument is a great word for describing the post climax events of a story or movie, but less applicable to games imo because the uncompleted events in games do not always focus on the same story as the main quest.

Answer (score 1):

For many Nintendo games, e.g. Super Mario Galaxy, it's called the **game**. The ostensible victory condition and end of the story (such as it is) are achieved very quickly, with perhaps 90% or more of the world and puzzles still remaining to be explored and completed.

Comment: +1 for managing to be sarcastic and still have a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this type of content would fall into the "optional content" category. So optional end-game content or optional post-game content make sense.